when mentioning prior art, do you want to specifically mention it by name?
So in the specs, if there is a current prior art who has implemented a feature that you want to mention and compare against your invention, do you just say "prior art" or do you want to be specific and mention the name of the prior art?
Any pros and cons of doing that?

"Prior  art" is a dirty word in a patent application. To you it means something that came before, to the examiner it means something they can use against you even if, for some technicality, it might arguably not actually qualify as prior art to your application. You calling it prior art makes "admitted prior art".
It is generally not considered good practice to be that specific when talking about your invention. Almost anything you say can be used against you. The specification is to describe your invention - what it is, how it works, and how to make it. When you say that previous thing X can't do Y but my invention can do Y, then any possible infringing process that doesn't happen to do Y might be deemed as not infringing even if it falls under the wording or one or more claims.
The time to explain the difference between X and your claims is when X is cited against you in an office action.

An excellent answer.

But if my invention is for a dating app, how do I reference the current existing dating apps if I don't use "prior art platforms", etc.?

“Existing platform”
